# How to filter data in a list using multiple conditions and LINQ?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I created this form to generate a list of students with the ability to filter by some criteria (on the left) and to display any information needed (from the right)
[image: List generation Form]

When the form is initializing at the start I am grabbing the whole student list with `Entity Framework`

```
List<Student> students = await context.Students.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And I am saving it into two lists:

```
private List<Student> _listOfAllStudents = new List<Student>();
private List<Student> _filteredStudents = new List<Student>();
```

Then I am performing my logic against the lists like this:

```
private void PrepareFilteredStudentListAccordingToFilterCheckedBoxes()
{
    _filteredStudents = _listOfAllStudents;

    if (ColonieFilterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        _filteredStudents = _filteredStudents.Intersect(_listOfAllStudents.Where(x => x.Colonie).Select(x => x).ToList()).ToList();
    }

    if (NatationFilterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        _filteredStudents = _filteredStudents.Intersect(_listOfAllStudents.Where(x => x.Nataion).Select(x => x).ToList()).ToList();
    }

    if (ExcursionFilterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        _filteredStudents = _filteredStudents.Intersect(_listOfAllStudents.Where(x => x.Excursion).Select(x => x).ToList()).ToList();
    }

    //Rest of the code is omitted but you get the idea...
}
```

Same logic is being done according to display checkboxes:

```
private void FillDataGridViewWithFilteredStudentAccordingToDisplayCheckBoxes()
{
    FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns.Add("Id", "Numero");
    FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns.Add("LastName", "Nom");
    FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns.Add("FirstName", "Prenom");

    if (MiddleNameDisplayCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns.Add("MiddleName", "Nom Du Pere");
    }

    if (BirthdayDateDisplayCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns.Add("DateOfBirth", "Date De Naissance");
    }

    //Rest of the code omitted, but same concept.

    foreach (Student student in _filteredStudents)
    {
        List<object> rowsValues = new List<object>();
        foreach (object column in FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns)
        {
            string columnName = ((DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)column).Name;

            if (columnName == "Id")
            {
                rowsValues.Add(student.StudentId);
            }

            if (columnName == "FirstName")
            {
                rowsValues.Add(student.FirstName);
            }
            //Code omitted.
        }
        object[] arrayRowsValues = rowsValues.ToArray();
        FilteredStudentDataGridView.Rows.Add(arrayRowsValues);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use `LINQ` instead of all those `if` blocks to filter the data according to my conditions?

Comment: Assuming `x.Colonie` and the others are bools this could work `Where(x => (x.Colonie && ColonieFilterCheckBox.Checked) && /*other conditions*/)` etc.

Comment: Note that `.Select(x => x)` is a null operation and isn't needed. Also, the inside `.ToList()` shouldn't be needed since `Intersect` takes an `IEnumerable`. Really, all you need is `_filteredStudents = _filteredStudents.Where(x => x.Excursion).ToList();`.

Comment: @JSteward Not all of them are `bool` but I can do this by checking if `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` since I don't let them insert data with empty strings

Comment: @NetMage Maybe I was just over thinking about it.. I guess.. Nice catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely move the filtering to the database:

```
IQueryable<Student> studentQuery = context.Students;
if (ColonieFilterCheckBox.Checked) {
    studentQuery = studentQuery.Where(x => x.Colonie);
}

if (NatationFilterCheckBox.Checked) {
    studentQuery = studentQuery.Where(x => x.Nataion);
}

if (ExcursionFilterCheckBox.Checked) {
    studentQuery = studentQuery.Where(x => x.Excursion);
}

var _filteredStudents = await studentQuery.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If you prefer local filtering logic, you can combine the conditions a little or use Reflection to simplify the code but slow it down some.

For combined conditions, you can do

```
_filteredStudents = _listOfAllStudents
    .Where(x => (!ColonieFilterCheckBox.Checked || x.Colonie) &&
                (!NatationFilterCheckBox.Checked || x.Natation) &&
                (!ExcursionFilterCheckBox.Checked || x.Excursion)).ToList();
```

but that checks the `CheckBox`s per `Student`.

Instead, using Reflection, you can build the code dynamically for the filter (again, assuming you name the `CheckBox` controls after the fields):

```
IEnumerable<Student> queryStudents = _listOfAllStudents;
var xParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student));

foreach (var filterField in new[] { "Colonie", "Natation", "Excursion" }) {
    if (((CheckBox)Controls.Find($"{filterField}CheckBox")).Checked) {
        var whereLambda = (Expression<Func<Student, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(xParm, filterField), xParm);
        queryStudents = queryStudents.Where(whereLambda.Compile());
    }
}
_filteredStudents = queryStudents.ToList();
```

For your display logic, I would rename all the check boxes to match the data field names, and then use a lot of Reflection:

```
private void FillDataGridViewWithFilteredStudentAccordingToDisplayCheckBoxes() {
    var headerText = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Id", "Numero" }, { "LastName", "Nom" }, { "FirstName", "Prenom" }, { "MiddleName", "Nom Du Pere" },
    { "DateOfBirth", "Date De Naissance" } };

    var viewColumns = new List<string> { "Id", "LastName", "FirstName" };

    foreach (var possibleColumn in headerText.Keys) {
        var displayColumns = Controls.Find(possibleColumn + "DisplayCheckBox", true);
        if (displayColumns.Length == 1) {
            if (((CheckBox)displayColumns[0]).Checked)
                viewColumns.Add(possibleColumn);
        }
    }

    //Rest of the code omitted, but same concept.

    foreach (var dataFieldName in viewColumns)
        FilteredStudentDataGridView.Columns.Add(dataFieldName, headerText[dataFieldName]);

    foreach (var student in _filteredStudents) {
        var studentType = student.GetType();
        var rowValues = new List<object>();
        foreach (var dataFieldName in viewColumns)
            rowValues.Add(studentType.GetProperty(dataFieldName).GetValue(student, null));

        FilteredStudentDataGridView.Rows.Add(rowValues.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Note that if you care about the order of the columns displayed, you will need some logic to order or sort the `headerText.Keys`. In my asp implementation of something similar, I just have a manual list of procedure calls with data names in the order that I want, and the procedure checks if the data item is to be displayed (in `viewColumns`), then adds the data and column header.

Comment: I didn't want to move all my filtering to the database, because in one session the user might be generating more than 20 lists, so it's faster to just filter the list I thought. About the reflection, it looks promising and will try it and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: You can use similar logic after retrieving the `Students` to create a local query. I think speed would depend on how many student records are retrieved versus database speed/latency.

Comment: @PaulKaram I couldn't resist adding some local options using more Reflection.

Comment: Thank you @NetMage and sorry for the slow responses, I am currently having issues in my home network connection so I can't test this directly, but I am assuming it will be a great help, once I am able to test them I will give you my feedback :)

Comment: Finally had the time to test this and it all worked out for me. Thank you. Just for info, I had to use `_filteredStudents = _listOfAllStudents.Where(x => (ColonieFilterCheckBox.Checked && x.Colonie) || (.. && ..) etc...)` instead of your code posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You could reuse your linq expressions in a single method. Try to use `AsQueryable` extension method from `System.Linq` namespace instead:

```
private ICollection<Student> FilterStudents(ICollection<Student> students)
{
    var query = students.AsQueryable();

    if (ColonieFilterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
       query  = query.Where(x=>x.Colonie);
    }

    if (NatationFilterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        query  = query.Where(x=>x.Nation);
    }

    if (ExcursionFilterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        query  = query.Where(x=>x.Excursion);
    }

   return query.ToList();
}
```